# Class "is not abstract and does not override abstract method" error

Tags: java, actionlistener

I am following a Java tutorial at https://youtu.be/64V8CC7nSok. I have copied the code 100% from the video, but still I get this error:

```
Board is not abstract and does not override abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener
```

I have already searched for similar cases, but it didn't help.

Here is the file with the error, `Board.java`, which is sufficient to reproduce the problem:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener{
    private Timer timer;

    public Board() {
        timer = new Timer(25, this);
        timer.start();
    }
    public void actionPeformed(ActionEvent e) {
        repaint();
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillRect(45, 60, 32, 32);
    }
}
```

Is it a problem that is not related to the coding but the software settings or version?

Comment: Can you modify your title, and post the actual error message in the question?

Comment: I would suggest finding a different tutorial. Among other issues (e.g. not using `@Override`) the video is 5 years old. Java has improved significantly in the intervening years.

Answer (score 0):

You misspelled actionPerformed!

Comment: use @Override to avoid such mistakes

Comment: @PhanindraGopishetty the tutorial OP is following doesn't use `@Override` :(